# GCP Speech-to-text API rejects to download transcript exported file (all type)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

Speech-to-txt API reject to download transcript exported file (all type) as when I click download it's show nothing even changed my browser / clean history/cookies etc... as below screenshot.

[image]

I try to download the exported file by GCP Console.

Comment: Are you encountering any error messages when attempting to download the file?